# Pairing android app with Bluetooth tire pressure sensors and getting real time data from it

Tags: android, bluetooth, real-time, sensors, connectivity

i m working on an android application which is going to get real time pressure data from Bluetooth enabled tire pressure sensors and display it on screen. From where should i start and how to pair my android app with Bluetooth enabled sensors? and how to get the real time data after pairing?

Please guide me through this, any help is highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those question....
First thing you need to do is to find out what profile the sensors are transmitting data with. For example, if it turns out to be Serial Port Profile - which is the most common one, you can literally copy and paste android chat sample code and change UUID to UUID of Serial Port.

Just replace UUID of the sample with this:
00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

This is the sample:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat

Comment: Well, thank you so much, got so much help, i hope i m gonna get through this.. :)